# I would like to know if my function is accurate. "sort_by_order function"

Tags: python

I would like to know if my function is accurate, and if there is anything unnecessary. "sort_by_order function"

```
from random import randrange

num = list() # the list we wish to arange
a=20         # you can change it as you want
while len(num)<a: 
    x=randrange(a)
    num.append(x)
print(num)    

def sort_by_ordre(un):
    x=0
    while x<(len(un)):
       x+=1
       for i in range(len(un)-1):
          if un[i]>un[i+1]:
             un[i],un[i+1]=un[i+1],un[i]
       
print('')
sort_by_ordre(num) # the function
print(num)
```

Comment: Your question is quite vague and does not meet SO rules, you did not describe a specific problem in your question, in case you wan't a code review, then you should post on [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Ruli when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it is missing context, which happens all too often.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ thanks for suggesting, next time I sure will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems correct. Bubble sort is inefficient.

For slightly faster bubble sorts, see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

```py
import random


def bubble_sort(x):
    size = len(x)
    for i in range(size):
        # Don't let j equal to (size - 1)
        # because x[j + 1] is out of bounds in
        # that case.
        for j in range(size - 1):
            # Swap x[j] and x[j + 1] if they
            # are in the wrong order
            if x[j] > x[j + 1]:
                x[j], x[j + 1] = x[j + 1], x[j]


def make_random_list(size=100):
    n = list(range(10))
    return [random.choice(n) for i in range(size)]


def main():
    for i in range(100):
        x = make_random_list()
        y = x.copy()
        bubble_sort(x)  # the function
        y.sort()
        assert x == y


main()
```